# Google Play search

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my game called [Doctor Who Quiz - Fantastic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.vilix.dwquiz), but I can't find it when searching on Google Play. That's not ood yet, because it's a new app and there are many similar apps with a similar name. The problem is, that I can't find it even on the last 'page' in results, but searching my name (as a developer name) or searching exact phrase from the description results in finding my app.

Why can't I see my app even on the last 'page' in results? It has been published 24 hours ago.

Comment: I'm not a Play expert, but I would imagine that it would take some time before it is indexed six ways to Sunday.

Comment: I would get that, but it is searchable using some phrases like my name or exact text from the app description.

Comment: Everything in the Google world is dictated by search. It might help if you do a bit of SEO to push your game up the search index.

Comment: I have tried that - I have the main keyword in the title and the description is full of keywords.